# Xcode 8.3.1 crashing at launch after adding unit tests

Tags: crash, xcode8

Suddenly Xcode has begun to crash at launch when I simply added a few unit tests. It works and runs fine in App Code. I've cleared derived data as well as the `xcuserdata` directories within the project. Any other ideas?

```
Process:               Xcode [26423]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.3.1 (12170)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-12170000000000000~7
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       821611362
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [26423]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-04-12 00:40:23.567 +0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.4 (16E195)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        A61178D2-CCD8-EB05-35BC-2919E1453F0A

Sleep/Wake UUID:       0957325A-2586-4141-9E55-27CBC55A7323

Time Awake Since Boot: 60000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
MainQueue: -[Xcode3TargetEntitlementsCoordinator syncPerformEntitlementsInteractionBlock:]_block_invoke
ProductBuildVersion: 8E1000a
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff3db72d8c0
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  5   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  6   -[Xcode3TargetEntitlementsCoordinatorToken allEntitlementKeys] (in DevToolsCore)
  7   __94-[Xcode3TargetCapabilitiesContext _appIDFeatureStateIncludingEntitlements:buildConfiguration:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
  8   DVTSyncPerformBlock (in DVTFoundation)
  9   -[Xcode3TargetEntitlementsCoordinator syncPerformEntitlementsInteractionBlock:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10   -[Xcode3TargetCapabilitiesContext _appIDFeatureStateIncludingEntitlements:buildConfiguration:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11   -[Xcode3Target appIDFeaturesForConfigurationNamed:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12   +[IDEProvisionableSnapshot snapshotFromProvisionable:overrides:] (in IDEFoundation)
 13   __72-[IDEProvisionableManager _evaluateStatusWithStatusEvaluator:overrides:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
 14   -[_DVTTimeSlicedMainThreadOrderedNonUniquingWorkQueue _processWorkItemsWithDeadline:] (in DVTFoundation)
 15   -[DVTTimeSlicedMainThreadWorkQueue _processWithDeadline:] (in DVTFoundation)
 16   -[_DVTTimeSlicedMainThreadActiveWorkQueues _processWorkQueuesOnDeadline] (in DVTFoundation)
 17   __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)
 18   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 19   __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 20   __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
 21   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 22   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 23   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 24   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 25   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 26   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 27   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 28   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 29   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 30   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 31   start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was the entitlements file. Accidentally it had some invalid entries and somehow that seems to have been the cause of the crash. Will file a radar.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, as you can see in the crash trace, the error was `Xcode3TargetEntitlementsCoordinator`. This in fact gave me a clue. The entitlements file somehow got modified and had a few missing xml end-tags, which caused Xcode to crash.